# MS SQL Converting Rows to Column

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I need to convert the table from (A) into (B).
I am able to get it work by joining the same table multiple times and use Max operator to assign the fields, but is there any better way to achieve this as Max operator could cause performance issue on huge table.
Can this be done by using pivot and will it cause any performance issue on huge table?
Btw, ID in below example is only 1 of the fields as example, there are other fields that need to achieve the same thing.

(A)
Class     ID    
1            11
1            12
1            13
2            11
2            12
2            13

(B)
Class    ID2    ID3    ID4
1            11     12       13
2            11
    12        13

Comment: There are lots and lots and lots of examples of turning rows to columns on this site. What have you researched and tried?

Comment: have you searched on PIVOT or on STUFF ?

Answer (score 1):

You can you `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
  ) pivot ( MAX(id) FOR id IN ([11],[12],[13]) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to go DYNAMIC

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(concat('ID',1+Row_Number() over (Partition By Class Order By ID))) From YourTable  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [Class],' + @SQL + '
From (
       Select [Class]
             ,ID
             ,Col = concat(''ID'',1+Row_Number() over (Partition By [Class] Order By [ID]))
         From YourTable 
     ) A
 Pivot (max(ID) For [Col] in (' + @SQL + ') ) P'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
Class   ID2 ID3 ID4
1       11  12  13
2       11  12  13
```

Comment: He's pivoting dynamically all over the place :)

Comment: @Prdp  :)  some folks just need a jump-start.